# BigQuery flattening both GA session and hit level fields in the same query

Tags: sql, google-analytics, bigdata, google-bigquery

In Standard SQL I want to be able to query the below all in the same query

- customDimensions
- hits.customDimensions
- hits.customMetrics
- hits.product.customDimensions

So far, I've come up with something like this (includes a UNION of two GA properties, one for mobile, the other for desktop) - I will be adding a lot more columns than this and I can't imagine having them all as sub-selects is the best approach:

```
SELECT
# standard session fields
date,
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
visitNumber,
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) visitStartTime,
totals.visits,
device.deviceCategory,
totals.hits,
totals.newVisits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.source,
channelGrouping,
device.browser,
device.browserSize,
device.browserVersion,
device.mobileDeviceInfo,
device.mobileDeviceModel,
device.operatingSystem,
device.mobileDeviceBranding,
geoNetwork.country,
geoNetwork.city,
# Session/User customDimension Example
(SELECT cd.value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) cd WHERE cd.index=20 and REGEXP_CONTAINS(cd.value, "\\d")) userId,

# hits customMetrics Example
SUM((SELECT SUM(hcm.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.customMetrics) hcm WHERE hcm.index=28)) totalBooking,

# hits customDimension Example
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hcd.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.customDimensions) hcd WHERE hcd.index=20)) h_cd1,

# hits products customDimension Example
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=1)) h_pc1,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=2)) h_pc2,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=3)) h_pc3,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=4)) h_pc4,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=5)) h_pc5,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=6)) h_pc6,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=7)) h_pc7,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=8)) h_pc8,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(hpc.value) FROM UNNEST(hits) h,UNNEST(h.product) hp,UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) hpc WHERE hpc.index=9)) h_pc9,

FROM (
  SELECT
  *
  FROM
  `abcdefgh.12345678.ga_sessions_*` desktopProperty
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180122' AND '20180122'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  *
  FROM
  `abcdefgh.12345678.ga_sessions_*` mobileProperty
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180122' AND '20180122'
  ) table
GROUP BY
  date,
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  visitStartTime,
  totals.visits,
  device.deviceCategory,
  totals.hits,
  totals.newVisits,
  totals.pageviews,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  trafficSource.adContent,
  trafficSource.campaign,
  trafficSource.keyword,
  trafficSource.medium,
  trafficSource.referralPath,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  device.browser,
  device.browserSize,
  device.browserVersion,
  device.mobileDeviceInfo,
  device.mobileDeviceModel,
  device.operatingSystem,
  device.mobileDeviceBranding,
  geoNetwork.country,
  geoNetwork.city,
  userId
ORDER BY
date
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly? You're asking how to make the expressions in the select list less verbose? If you want to sum values for various values of `index` you could potentially define a SQL UDF and call that instead.

Comment: Yes, less verbose I'd say. I guess I'm trying to validate that the above method is the most efficient way to go about it. I'm trying to create a query that will essentially have a row per session with a lot of columns that include session level fields and aggregation of hit level fields.

Comment: I feel like having a more complete example in your question would help. It's hard to tell what will be redundant in the actual query.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated the post to include a more complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stay on session level you don't need a `GROUP BY`, because the source table already is on session scope. So you can get rid of that. Then you also have to remove the aggregation functions around your sub-selects. Simply bring everything to the desired scope -

Example for bringing different scopes to session level:

```
SELECT
  date AS sessionScope,
  (SELECT count(hitNumber) FROM t.hits) hitScope,
  (SELECT SUM(IF(cd.value='example',1,0)) FROM t.hits AS h, h.customDimensions cd WHERE cd.index=1) hitCdScope,
  (SELECT COUNT(p.productSku) FROM t.hits AS h, h.product AS p WHERE h.ecommerceaction.action_type='6') productScope
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20180127` AS t
WHERE
  totals.transactions > 0
LIMIT
  1000
```

Comment: Perfect, thank, you for the explanation! and of course, GROUP BY is not needed if attempting to have everything in a session scope.

Comment: Also, in the sub-selects, I'm able to directly access the table and records as well as unnesting them. Is there a point of unnesting or not?

Comment: Certain table operations don't work with arrays - in these cases, you have to unnest them before. I'm simply not using it, unless bq complains that this array is not a table ;)

Comment: Ah, makes total sense. I will go with that approach, if it moans, unnest! Thanks again

Comment: Maybe something to note: 
When unnesting you also destroy the order of elements. For arrays, you can do something like `hits[OFFSET(0)]`. That's why there is this extension giving you an index: `UNNEST(hits) WITH OFFSET AS index`

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember seeing this in the documentation. When unnesting is needed, I will use the offset